# Best DBMS to store HTML

Tags: html, database

What is the best opensource java integrated DBMS  to store HTML pages?
...In term of performance, scalability, usability and more...
thanks to all

Comment: I have to do some kind of CMS within a system already developed with a lot of critical problem (security and more...).
I need something that:
1 is fast
2 give me support for research.

So I think to a database.

Comment: It isn't clear if you need a new CMS, or just a search engine.

Comment: Sorry! 
Well, I need for a system that simulates a CMS. I have to edit the HTML pages on the fly and I have to quickly search for view.

Answer (score 2):

I think any filesystem will beat any DB hands down in terms of ease-of-use, manageability, structuring, etc. Provided you have sane directory layout (which is great for management purposes) scalability and performance should not be a problem. In fact, I'm even tempted to think that performance will be higher compared to that of a DBMS (for instance, your web server can serve HTML pages directly. Most modern filesystems support transactions, so this should not be an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could store in a file system and use Apache Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

Html is tag soup. If you want special support for xml tools like xpath, you can look into databases with xml support, like PostgreSQL and Oracle, and store xhtml in them. If you don't need it, go with the filesystem.